# Will my health insurance provider report my STD testing to my (policy holder) parents?

Tags: health-insurance

I'm an 18 year old male looking to get a 10 panel STD test done in Illinois. The testing is a bit expensive, but according to my parents insurance provider, Blue Cross Blue Shield, which I am covered under, the cost of the test should be covered. However, I don't necessarily want them to be aware that I am getting a test, as it is not a conversation I want to have. So my question is, if I get the test and ask insurance to pay for it, does the insurance send some form of "notice" that the testing was covered to my parents?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask the insurance company that question but the answer is probably yes. What they receive probably won't say what the test was. It will most likely just list the company that billed it plus something generic like "laboratory."

Under US law the insurance company [can't discuss](https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/faq/disclosures-to-family-and-friends) what the bill was for with your parents without your written consent, but I'd say they're going to be curious and probably concerned when they see the bill so you're going to need an explanation. I can't imagine any lies that would be believable. If I were them I would think either you have a medical problem you're not telling us about or they were STD tests, and as a parent I'd much rather find out it was the latter. It's not unreasonable for a college student to seek STD testing.

One thing to consider is unless you're trying out for a role in a porn flick, do you really need a full battery of tests? While some STDs can be silent (eg, HIV), most come with symptoms, at least initially.